# Counting new lines, tabs, and spaces

Tags: c++

I'm working my way through C++ Primer 5th edition to teach myself C++.  I came across a problem in the book that I don't know how to solve in Chapter 5 using the tools they have given me thus far.  I have previous programming experience and have solved this myself using `noskipws`.  I'm looking for help on how to solve this problem with minimal use of libraries, think the first 4-5 chapters of a beginner book.

The problem is to find and count all the vowels, spaces, tabs, and newline characters as they are read using if statements.  My solution to the problem is:

```
// Exercise 5.9
int main() 
{
char c;
int aCount = 0;
int eCount = 0;
int iCount = 0;
int oCount = 0;
int uCount = 0;
int blankCount = 0;
int newLineCount = 0;
int tabCount = 0;   
while (cin >> noskipws >> c) 
{       
    if( c == 'a' || c == 'A')
        aCount++;
    else if( c == 'e' || c == 'E')
        eCount++;
    else if( c == 'i' || c == 'I')
        iCount++;
    else if( c == 'o' || c == 'O')
        oCount++;
    else if( c == 'u' || c == 'U')
        uCount++;       
    else if(c == ' ')
        blankCount++;       
    else if(c == '\t')
        tabCount++;     
    else if(c == '\n')
        newLineCount++;     
}
cout << "The number of a's: " << aCount << endl;
cout << "The number of e's: " << eCount << endl;
cout << "The number of i's: " << iCount << endl;
cout << "The number of o's: " << oCount << endl;
cout << "The number of u's: " << uCount << endl;
cout << "The number of blanks: " << blankCount << endl;
cout << "The number of tabs: " << tabCount << endl;
cout << "The number of new lines: " << newLineCount << endl;    
return 0;
}
```

The only other way I can think to solve this is using getline() and then counting the amount of times it loops to get the '/n' count and then step through each string to find the '/t' and ' '.

Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The way you're doing it seems fine to me! If you're looking for a way to shorten your code you could place the chars you're searching for in a data structure and then check each char against it. But your implementation gets the job done.

Comment: I'm looking how to solve this problem without using something like noskipws.  I want to know how the book is expecting this problem to be solved with the limited things they have given me so far. noskipws isn't brought up for another 10 chapters.

Comment: Additionally you might use either `tolower()` or `toupper()` for the vowels, so you can compactify your code a Little.

Comment: Well you could use `getline()` and basically use the exact same logic you have now. You'd just be looping the required number of times, and looping through chars in each string instead of all the chars.

Comment: I thought about that but I thought getline() drops '/n'.  So the only way to get the count is to count the number of times the while loop fires.

Comment: That's true, but you're right, `getline()` uses \n as it's delimiter by default. So that's a perfectly fine way to count the lines.

Comment: Please use a switch statement.  You might find it cleans up your code quite a bit.

Comment: @Steve Wellens I know but it was a requirement of the problem to use if statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid `noskipws` by replacing this

```
while (cin >> noskipws >> c)
```

with

```
while ( cin.get(c) )
```

The extraction operator `>>` observes delimiter rules, including whitespace.

[`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) does not, and extracts the data verbatim.

Comment: This does work but my only problem with it is get also isn't mentioned in the book for another 8 or so chapters, only getline() has been mentioned so far.  I'm starting to think the solution to this particular question was an oversight by the authors because the tools like get and noskipws have not been introduced.

Comment: @MK And what's the problem with `getline()`? Sure, it drops the newline, but you can test for the stream's `eof()` and if that isn't set, the newline was there.

Comment: @MK Perhaps.  The "only other way" you mention is also solid.

Comment: @Angew nothing is wrong with getline(), the book has not taught how to test for eof() yet, that isn't mentioned until chapter 8.  I was hesitant to even post this question because I knew I would get a lot of good answers.  My main question was how to solve it without using most tools, and since eof() hasn't been mentioned I have to exclude it from what the author was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works [perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/1QfgZY):

**Input:**

```
This is a test or something
New line
12345
Test 21
```

**Output:**

```
The number of a's: 1
The number of e's: 5
The number of i's: 4
The number of o's: 2
The number of u's: 0
The number of blanks: 7
The number of tabs: 0
The number of new lines: 3
```

I'd recommend checking out the [std::tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/tolower/)() function, for testing upper and lowercase characters at the same time.
Also, to check for *any* kind of letter, look into the [std::isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isalpha/)() [std::isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isdigit/)(), [std::isspace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isspace/)(), and similar functions.

Further, you could make the function not dependant on std::cin, and instead use std::cin to get a string, and pass the string into the function, that way the function could be used for any string, not just std::cin input.

To avoid using ***noskipws*** (which I personally think is fine), one option is to do this: (as an alternative option to the other solutions already offered)

```
std::string str;
//Continue grabbing text up until the first '#' is entered.
std::getline(cin, str, '#');
//Pass the string into your own custom function, to keep your function detached from the input.
countCharacters(str);
```

(See [here for an example](http://ideone.com/zn1jUX))

Comment: Thanks I will check those out.